# What view controller should I use for back and forth communication?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an app in progress that requires communication between two already identified users (not messenging or SMS). The data is persisted remotely however the UI needs to be dead simple  . Is there a iMessage type view controller that is available that i can use? I really like the one I have attached below, just not sure how to get it or even if someone has better ideas?

[image]

Comment: That's a table view with fancy cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of pre-made bubble controls:

- [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat)
- [PTSMessagingCell](https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSMessagingCell/)
- [SSMessagesViewController](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller)
- [UIBubbleTableView](https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView)

There are also some you can purchase at [CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com).